# How to sort vertices by edge count in OrientDB

Tags: sql, graph-databases, orientdb

I want to do this but it doesn't work:

```
select * FROM Users ORDER BY in.size()
```

I have also tried:

```
select * from Users ORDER BY in[label='connection'].size()
select * from Users ORDER BY inE['connection'].size()
```

it just returns all V's but not sorted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably more what you were looking for.

```
select *, in().size() as size from Users order by size desc
```

My understanding is that that will take all incoming edges into the count. If you only need to look at a specific edge, try the following.

```
select *, in_myEdge.size() as size from Users order by size desc
```

However, if you use the wrong edge name, the query won't give you and error and simply return a bogus result.

ORDER BY is currently supported only on projection fields and will be a feature in future releases.

Comment: The second query should be: "select *, in('in_myEdge').size() as size from Users order by size desc" (note the call to IN()).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * FROM Users LET $c = in.size() ORDER BY $c
```

Comment: it has no effect still the order is by rid while i can see in the studio the edges.

Comment: This won't work as ORDER BY is currently supported only on projection fields. That said, it will be available in a future release.